# Generate small UID with uniqueness

Tags: java, hibernate, security, uuid, birthday-paradox

I need to generate the UID (alphanumeric) for my use case but that should be a maximum of 7 characters long as we want UID to be random but manageable, like a **PNR** (CYB6KL) for example.
Now if I am not wrong, I can generate a random UID that is small, but uniqueness might be compromised because of collisions (birthday paradox), so for 32 bits, 50% collision probability would be around 77k UID generations.

So in essence, I need a way to generate UIDs that are:

1. Small (max 7 character)
2. Random
3. Unique
4. Don't require lookups for the previous existance.

I will be storing this UID in a database column and it's imperative that the UID is unique. It will NOT be the table's primary key which right now is an autogenerated ID.

I am thinking of something along the lines, but I am not sure about uniqueness.

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger(32, new SecureRandom());
return big.toString(32).toUpperCase();
```

Really appreciate any thoughts that might help on this. Generation must be unique.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a part that is derived from the system time and a part that is random.

Comment: @dan1st
Can you please explain? Do you mean something like

    **BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis).toString(32);**

Comment: This is practically impossible. What *is* possible is adding a unique constraint to the database column and generate random ids until there is no error on insertion. This would be a lookup though, but inherent to the database insert.

Comment: Base32 seems rather wasteful if you only have a few characters to spend. What character range is allowed for each character? I could possibly use a *pseudo*-random value by encrypting a counter with a secret key using format preserving encryption. That, uh, may take some study...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes So I need a 7 character alphanumeric string. A-Z, 0-9

Comment: Base 36 in other words, I think you can just use 36 in the call. log_2(36^7) is slightly more than 36 (by "accident" I assume). That's only a bit more than 7 * 5 =35 for base32, but every bit counts I suppose.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes but still I would have to check for uniqueness before each persistance, right?

Comment: Yes, of course, even 1 in 2^36 for **two** values is not enough to make it obvious that there will be no collisions. Sure it is more likely that you win the lottery, but this kind of stuff can easily come back and bite you. Hence my other hint about using format preserving encryption. With about 128 bits you can be reasonably sure that there are no collisions and I would use more bits for  lots of values.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes so what's your recommendation in general?

Comment: Well, unless my trick with the secret & FPE works, work around the issue and / or use a (centrally managed) counter instead.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Let me figure out the optimal way to solve this. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [hashids](https://hashids.org/) for this purpose which implements a bimorphic translation that can encode a numeric value into a string code with a custom alphabet. This should do exactly what you want. If you need this to be traversal-secure, you should use some kind of `SecureRandom` as source for the underlying numeric value. If not, you could even base this on the auto increment value you already have. The benefit of reusing the primary key is that you can just translate the string code and do a lookup by primary key.